# How to set the same padding size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a image on my webpage and I don't understand why the padding is only setting on the left side.
The right side doesn't show any margin.

This is my CSS:

```
#main {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) .noo-container {
  max-width: 750px;
  width: 100%;
}

.noo-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcapti figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

* {
  font-family: "helvetica", "arial", "sans-serif";
}
```

I'm expected to have the same margin on the left and the right.

The page is https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/home/.

Comment: It's looking good. Where was the issue?

Comment: the right size is without any margin and the left side has a margin.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by using the "background-image" property on a div. It is significantly easier and more common to use the  tag.

```html
<div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg">
    <img src="https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/HEAD1-1024x532.jpg">
</div>
```

```css
.bgimg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: inherit;
    z-index: 20;
}
.bgimg img {
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 21px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element the `<div>` with `class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_row-no-padding"` has  `left: -88.5px;width: 1349px`. Thats causing the issue here.Make it as `left: 0;width: 100%`. Next remove this `class="site-main noo-container"`  from the `<main>` as you have mentioned `max-width`

```
<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" data-vc-stretch-content="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_row-no-padding" style="position: relative;/* left: -88.5px; */box-sizing: border-box;width: 100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS contains a lot of conflicting data:

Both of these are called using `id="main"`, so, which is it supposed to be?

```
#main {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Then here, you indicate that a `width: 100%;` which conflicts with your `margin-right:auto;` and `margin-left:auto;` settings.  And... while you indicated settings for `padding-left:15px`/`padding-right:15px`, you may be better off using `padding: auto;` which would actually center the content from all 4 directions.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) .noo-container {
  max-width: 750px;
  width: 100%;
}

.noo-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set class and id second time. In the fact, you can, but it's nonsense, it orverrides.